# JProfiler shows maximum of 60 threads in Spring Boot

Tags: jprofiler

Below are the technologies used
Springboot starter web
Springboot starter JPA
Docker container (sperateseparate for BE and FE)
Hikari CP for Connection pool
Web server is Linux EC Instance with 16Gb of RAM and 4 vCPUs RDS is 8Gb , 2 VCPUs

Why is that

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what the question is. Do you think there should be more or less threads? Why?